# How to run a script from local on remote but at some point continue running the script on the local server?

Tags: bash, ssh, local, remote-server

I need to run a bash script that takes some parameters from server-1 and then from my local server where I ran the script with

```
ssh user@server-1 bash -s <script.sh
```

I then need to use those parameters to be executed with all kind of commands on my local server and also server-2 is involved. But the script will still be running on server-1 because of

```
ssh user@server-1 bash -s <script.sh
```

Maybe I can use 2 scripts but I want them to be only on local server. and putting in the script more commands after SSH doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: the script.sh is run by the bash process running remote which means that current bash process forks (and waits for its termination) a ssh process which is waiting for the termination of remote process the remote process doesn't know about the process which called first, the next commands must be placed after the ssh command which must be in another script than script.sh, if all should be put in one script maybe functions should be used to isolate the process and a logic added to determine the context and execute the right process

Answer (score 0):

I would place the script on the remote server and remote execute it via SSH.
If the script should change over time, then break it up into 2-3 steps
1. gather any additional parameter from remote machine
2. copy script to remote machine using scp
3. ssh to "remote execute" script on remote machine

Am not sure what parameter you need from the remote system.
I would try to hand it over via command line options to the script in #3.
Otherwise "hack"/patch it in before #2.

Comment: I ahve seperated the script into 2 parts     #!/bin/bash
PATH=`ssh $1 bash -s <tester.sh $2`  
scp -3 user@server1:/etc/somepath/$2/file.txt user@server2:$PATH
but when I run the script it says that scp command not found even though it works if I run it in the bash and all the parameters we taken successfully. Sorry, I can't paragraph this because when I click enter it saves the comment.

Comment: Set PATH variable proper in all scripts and export it. PATH=/foo:/bar ; export PATH